# Javascript long polling a json file - angularjs/jquery

Tags: python, django

Wishing you a Happy New year.!

I am having trouble when i am trying to load a json file from my web server. Actually i do not know java script. I just need this code to work. I am developing a website using Django. One of the django views, serves the client side java script and at the back end on a separate thread, it process some modules and generates a json output.

Now i am accessing this json using the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addmsg(msg) {
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function waitForMsg() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% static ""%}tmp/{{url_hash}}/{{url_json}}",

            cache: false,
            timeout: 50000,

            success: function (data) {
                addmsg(data);
                if (!data) {
                    setTimeout(
                        waitForMsg,
                        1500
                    );
                };
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                addmsg("error");
                setTimeout(waitForMsg, 15000);
            }

        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        waitForMsg();
        addmsg("loading");
    });
</script>
```

When i run this, javascript gets served and then it queries for the json file every 1.5 sec.

What happens is, once the file is available on the server, this script loads the file and redirects the page to something like this ,

> localhost:8000/+e+/

I dono from where this is getting redirected. I am not redirecting on any views or urls.py is clean.

Please help me with a code which will load this json from webserver when its available and then print the contents.

Thanks

===========update------------------

can anyone please suggest me angular js script for achieving the same ? thanks

==================== Update =====================================

Found the error, Actually the json dict has javascript, which has } { and quotes. Which breaks it.

Comment: Re your edit, AngularJS won't help you yet. You've got a basic problem connecting JavaScript with your server. The problem isn't jquery, and won't be solved by changing to another framework.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking beyond a lack of knowledge about JavaScript and stepping through all the parts of your problem. For example, use chrome and open the developer tools tab. Reload the page. Look at the url the JavaScript is testing to open. I suspect it is not the url you intend.

This code looks odd:

```
{% static ""%
```

Why is there the quote in the middle of the django directive? This isn't a JavaScript issue, just a quoting issue. It's also a warning sign because your JavaScript is using template directives - not an impossible or illegal thing, but a concern that some teams wouldn't allow.

In any case, track down the url that is actually bring invoked, see if it is the one you intend, and check the quoting issue in the httpcall.

Comment: I am just loading the static path there. Its getting parsed correctly. I checked the HTML source. Even if i change that. i am getting the same results.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do with the django directive. I'm suggesting that you are doing it wrong. I don't see how the url could be right with the quote char in that place. Also, why is it using a static url for a view call? Weird. What is the url of the view call? In the chrome dev tools, is that definitely what your JavaScript accesses?